# Travel insurance does not cover Spain. Will it be OK for a French Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, france, insurance

I am applying for a Schengen visa shortly at the French consulate in London through TLScontact. I plan to visit only France for 5 days. I have purchased a travel insurance from the Post office which says it covers entire Europe except Spain, Cyprus and Turkey. As Spain is part of the Schengen area will there be a problem if I use this for my visa application?

Comment: It needs to be for whole Schengen, as once you get visa, theoretically you can visit any place in Schengen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See on [page 10](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:en:PDF) (Article 15):

> 3. The insurance shall be valid throughout the territory of the Member States  and cover the entire period of the person’s intended stay or transit. The    minimum coverage shall be EUR 30 000.

In general I would not expect any insurance that does not specifically state that it is Schengen compliant to be adequate.